# Firestore - Double render and infinite loop while using useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I need some help with **React** and **Firestore**.
Somehow when I get the data from firestore and log it into the console the data is logged twice. And when I assign the data from firestore to the blog variable with useState, the whole function jumps into an infinite loop.

Here is the code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { projectFirestore } from '../../firebase/config';

const Blogs = () => {
    const [blog, setBlog] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        projectFirestore
        .collection("Blogs")
        .get()
        .then(querySnapshot => {
            querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                const data = doc.data()
                console.log(data)

            });
        });
    }, [blog])



    return (
        <div>
            Blogs
        </div>
    )
}
export default Blogs
```

Any suggestions on why does the data keep getting logged twice to the log and why does it keep getting into infinite loop when I try to use useState? Thanks for any help

Comment: Delete the blog variable from useEffect dependency array, because on the effect runs on first render and will set in the blog data into the state, but i you put the blog into the dependency array the effect will rerun on blog chages and you get an inf loop, cause the effetct set the state, the state changes and again.

Comment: I deleted it and still the same.

Comment: Do you get infinity loop or double log? Btw i cant see the setBlog(data) method.

Comment: The setBlog(data) should go right after console.log(data). The double log got eliminated with the useEffect, I just forgot to mention that. My bad.

Comment: could you solve the issue then?

Comment: I have changed the component from function to class, and it did solve the infinite loop problem. But now I have problem with the async. The state does not get populated even though I am using promise. Async/await did not help either.

Comment: It's the double log and infinite loop solved? If so I'll suggest that @DánielBoros should put the comment in an answer and mark it as solved so people with the same problem can find it fast and easy. And if you need it you can create a new question with your Async/away problem.

Answer (score 0):

In this form you shoudnt get infinity loop in useEffect.

```
const [blog, setBlog] = useState<Array<{}>>([])

useEffect(() => {
        projectFirestore
        .collection("Blogs")
        .get()
        .then(querySnapshot => {
            querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                const data = doc.data()
                console.log(data)
                setBlog(prevState => [...prevState, data])
            });
        });
    }, [])
```